# Find the Coefficient of $x^{25}$ in....

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, multinomial-coefficients

Find the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $(1+x^3+x^8)^{10}$ using ordinary generating functions?

Could someone help me figure out this problem using generating functions? My initial thought was to using a substituting variable (like $y=x^3$ and substituting accordingly), but I couldn't find a variable that would work. I would really appreciate some help! A detailed answer is always great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is a method that makes critical use of generating functions.

Comment: Well, there are certain functions like:
$1+x^2+x^3+... = \frac{1}{1-x}$;
$(1+x)^n = 1 + C(n,1)x + C(n,2)x^2...$;
$(1-x^m)^n = 1 - C(n,1)x^m + C(n,2)n^2m + (-1)^k C(n,k)x^{km}$
That can help figure out the coefficient, but I'm not sure what to use in this case...

Comment: The only way I can think of "using generating functions" is to identify $(1+x^3+x^8)^{10}$ as the generating function of a certain sequence $(a_n)$, and finding $a_{25}$ in some combinatorial way.

Comment: I'd consider the first of those to be a generating function, but I think nothing like it is applicable here. The other two are just the binomial theorem, which you can certainly use here (in fact, I'm not sure you have any choice) but I think it leads to a lot of computation.

Comment: $\large\tt 2520$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{{\,\left.\right\vert\,}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

\begin{align}
\pars{1 + x^{3} + x^{8}}^{10}
&= \sum_{\ell = 0}^{10}{10 \choose \ell}\pars{x^{3} + x^{8}}^{\ell}
=\sum_{\ell = 0}^{10}{10 \choose \ell}x^{3\ell}\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\ell}{\ell \choose \ell'}x^{5\ell'}\sum_{n = 0}^{80}\delta_{n,3\ell + 5\ell'}
\end{align}

> $$
> \pars{1 + x^{3} + x^{8}}^{10}= \sum_{n = 0}^{80}a_{n}x^{n}
> $$
> where
> $$
> a_{n} =
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{10}{10 \choose \ell}
> \sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\ell}{\ell \choose \ell'}\delta_{5\ell',n - 3\ell}
> =
> \sum_{\ell = 0
>       \atop
>       {\vphantom{\Huge A}0\ \leq\ {n - 3\ell \over 5}\ \leq\ \ell}}^{10}
> {10 \choose \ell}{\ell \choose {n - 3\ell \over 5}}
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad 5 \isdiv \pars{n - 3\ell}
> $$

$$
\color{#ff0000}{%
a_{n} =
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{lcl}
\quad\sum_{\ell = 0
      \atop
      {\vphantom{\Huge A}{n \over 8}\ \leq\ \ell\ \leq\ {n \over 3}}}^{10}
{10 \choose \ell}{\ell \choose {n - 3\ell \over 5}}
\quad\mbox{and}\quad 5 \isdiv \pars{n - 3\ell}\,,
& \color{#0000ff}{\mbox{if}} & 0 \leq n \leq 80
\\[3mm]
\quad 0\,, && \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.}
$$

> \begin{align}
> a_{25} &=
> \sum_{\ell = 0
>       \atop
>       {\vphantom{\Huge A}{25 \over 8}\ \leq\ \ell\ \leq\ {25 \over 3}}}^{10}
> {10 \choose \ell}{\ell \choose {25 - 3\ell \over 5}}
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad 5 \isdiv \pars{25 - 3\ell}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \sum_{\ell = 4}^{8}
> {10 \choose \ell}{\ell \choose {25 - 3\ell \over 5}}
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad 5 \isdiv \pars{25 - 3\ell}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {10 \choose 5}{5 \choose {25 - 3\times 5 \over 5}}
> =
> {10 \choose 5}{5 \choose 2} = {10! \over 5!\,5!}\,{5! \over 2!\,3!}
> =
> {10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \over 1}\,{1 \over 2 \times 3 \times 2}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large a_{25} = 2520}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to use generating functions for this.  You are looking for compositions of $25$ with up to $10$ parts of $8$ and $3$.  You can use $25=8+8+3+3+3$, which is the only one.  So now you want a series of $10$ items, with $5\ \ 0$'s, $3\ \ 3$'s, and $2\ \ 8$'s.  How many is that?